# Dans quels cas les sujets au singulier décrivant une multitude se conjuguent-ils comme des pluriels ?

Tags: accord, pluriel, noms-collectifs

Par exemple, est-il préférable de dire :

> Un nombre incalculable de personnes **ont entendu** la détonation.

(auquel cas on considère, par syllepse, que le très grand nombre de sujets impose une conjugaison au pluriel)

ou

> Un nombre incalculable de personnes **a entendu** la détonation.

(qui, en toute logique ou techniquement parlant, accorde le groupe verbal avec le singulier du nom *nombre*)

La question se pose aussi bien avec d'autres formes comme

- une foule de ...
- un groupe de ...
- une douzaine de ...
- la plupart des ...
- etc.

Comment: Remarque : c'est pas un nombre qui a entendu quoi que ce soit, se sont bien les personnes qu'il regroupe qui ont entendu la détonation. L'expression « un nombre de … » dénote rarement le nombre lui-même, et l'exemple que tu donnes l'illustre très bien. Après, je crois qu'on est libre de choisir l'accord sémantique ou l'accord syntaxique…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Selon le guide de grammaire d'[Antidote](http://www.druide.com/a_description.html) et l'article sur [les noms collectifs](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1443) de la Banque de dépannage linguistique de l'Office québécois de la langue française (OQLF), lorsque le sujet d'un verbe est un nom collectif singulier accompagné d'un complément pluriel, l'accord peut se faire soit avec le nom collectif, soit avec son complément, selon que l'on veuille insister sur la globalité ou sur les individus.

De manière générale, lorsque le nom collectif est précédé d'un pronom défini, l'accord se fera avec le nom collectif. Ce n'est cependant pas toujours le cas. Lorsque le nom collectif est précédé d'un pronom indéfini, l'accord peut se faire avec le nom collectif ou son complément.

Il faut principalement garder en tête qui effectue l'action; le nom collectif ou les particules qu'il comporte. Prenons cet exemple :

> La file de clients à l'entrée s'allonge

C'est la file qui s'allonge, non les clients. Il serait donc erroné d'accorder le verbe au pluriel dans ce cas-ci. D'autres exemples peuvent être trouvés sur le site de l'OQLF.

Antidote fait également cette remarque :

Quand ils ne sont pas précédés d’un article, nombre de et quantité de jouent le rôle de déterminant; c’est donc le nombre du nom que prend le verbe.

> Quantité de mesures seront prises pour éviter l’émeute.
>
> Bon nombre de journalistes couvriront l’évènement.

Comment: Je ne vois pas dans quel cas « la file de clients » pourrait être considérée comme une entité plurielle. La file de clients sont… ?

Comment: « File » est un nom collectif, il est impossible d'avoir une file qui ne comporte qu'une seule entité. On pourrait dire « La file de clients s'impatientent », puisque ce sont les clients qui font l'action de s'impatienter.

Comment: Ben, je veux bien voir un exemple extrait de la littérature. *Un certain nombre de personnes sont allés…*, ou *une douzaine de personnes sont allés…* pas de problème, mais pour les autres je reste perplexe.

Comment: La réponse est déjà relativement informative (+1) mais je reste un peu dubitatif... il me semble que des constructions comme *Une multitude de personnes sont parties* ou *Une foule de pensées envahissaient son esprit* continueront à me choquer un peu, et à me faire douter énormément. Mais il faut peut-être que j'apprenne à accepter cette part d'indécision... ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI Certains cas de grammaire peuvent choquer, certes, mais je ne crois pas pouvoir être beaucoup plus claire. Tiré mot pour mot de l'OQLF : « Lorsque le nom collectif est accompagné d'un complément, l'accord du verbe se fait soit avec le collectif, soit avec son complément, selon que l'on considère de manière individuelle ou collective les êtres dont on parle. » Les deux sont corrects. J'ai tenté d'éclaircir les cas où l'un peut être préférable à l'autre. Je suis désolée que ce bout de grammaire vous déplaise, mais reste qu'il s'agit de la réponse à votre question.

Comment: @Kareen Je sens au ton de ta réponse que j'ai oublié de dire le principal : merci beaucoup à toi pour tes recherches, c'était très pertinent ;-) En réalité, la raison sous-jacente de mon insatisfaction, c'est que ma question avait pour but d'améliorer ce point dans mon générateur de phrases (voir profil) car certains utilisateurs m'ont parfois signalé ce type de constructions qui les choquaient. Mon programme saura difficilement gérer la partie *selon que l'on considère de manière individuelle ou collective les êtres dont on parle*. Ah c'est difficile d'apprendre à parler à une machine ! :-)

Comment: @RomainVALERI Héhé, oui, dans ce contexte, je peux comprendre que la réponse soit décevante! Les machines et les langues naturelles ont souvent de la difficulté à communiquer entre elles. Peut-être que quelqu'un d'autre arrivera à dénicher quelque chose de plus systématique qui saura t'aider davantage :)

Comment: @RomainVALERI Ah, bah oui, tu frappes précisément dans un problème classique de la linguistique informatique: un engin programmé ne traite pas ou très mal les nuances de nature stylistique, rhétorique ou sémantique, catégories dans lesquelles l'emploi de la syllepse se retrouve.

Answer (score 2):

> Un nombre incalculable de personnes ont entendu la détonation.

Parler courant : accord proximal, fluide à l'oreille

> Un nombre incalculable de personnes a entendu la détonation.

Parler recherché : accord distal, l'intellect est à la recherche de la référence indiquée par ce verbe [au] singulier.

Il y a donc de fortes chances de rencontrer la première forme dans l'oralité, ou dans l'usage quotidien ; ce qui devrait permettre de générer des séquences courantes avec la première formule, et d'ajouter le subjonctif ou des formes plus rares de conjugaisons pour la seconde.

... et de compléter au choix : Créer une phrase [ usuelle | académique].

De longues réflexions sur la connaissance de la langue (et donc de soi) solubles dans la programmation intuitive à venir.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ces précisions ! Et en effet, la route est encore longue...

Comment: Egalement : ce concept d'accord proximal/distal est intéressant ! J'ai donc fait une recherche google sur *accord distal* >>> 3 résultats... 2 erronés, 1 hors contexte.

Comment: Ignorant le vocabulaire grammatical, j'utilise ces mots d'origine médicale, avec l'idée qu'en acuponcture, le point distal (au poignet ou au bout d'un doigt) agit de manière puissante sur l'organe visé (par exemple le cœur). Heureusement http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/distal apporte une précision linguistique favorable et Le Robert (rubrique didactique) : qui fonctionne à distance : le système olfactif est distal, le système gustatif proximal - *proximité de l'accord*, et *distance des mots accordés* rendrait-il la même idée avec la même force? - je crois que j'userai encore de ces mots en -al.

Comment: J'étais déçu de ne rien trouver, c'est vrai, mais il n'empêche que j'ai immédiatement compris ce dont tu parlais, et la distinction m'a parue lumineuse, donc je ne considère pas que le terme était mal choisi, je vais même probablement le réemployer...