# Conjugaison du verbe quand le sujet est un nom collectif

Tags: accord, pluriel, sujet, noms-collectifs

Aujourd'hui ma femme qui est française m'a dit que ce deux phrases sont correctes:

> La plupart des élèves comprend le sujet.
>
> La plupart des élèves comprennent le sujet.

J'aurais pensé que la deuxième n'était pas correcte car le sujet de la phrase est singulier mais le verbe est pluriel.  J'ai cru que c'était comme ça car c'est la règle en anglais.  Cependant, elle m'a dit que les deux sont possibles, mais elle n'a pas pu me donner la règle.

Qu'est-ce que c'est la règle en français?

Comment: Question probablement similaire à [celle-ci](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/dans-quels-cas-les-sujets-au-singulier-decrivant-une-multitude-se-conjuguent-ils) ?

Comment: Tu as raison.  Je ne pouvais pas trouvé la tienne quand j'ai posé cette question.  Merci pour me l'avoir montré.  J'ai changé la titre de ma question pour être plus général à l'avenir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La question des syllepses (terme technique: les anglophones parlent souvent d'*accord sémantique* pour le même concept) en français est plutôt complexe. Elle couvre une dizaine de pages dans Grevisse (§§435-440) rien que pour les syllepses verbales.

Grevisse classe le cas de *la plupart* (§438 a. 4<sup>o</sup>) comme une syllepse obligatoire: l'accord se fait systématiquement au pluriel en français contemporain. L'usage du singulier est considéré archaïsant.

Comment: Pluriel *féminin* ? Parce que la plupart des mots sont féminines ? :-)

Comment: Argh! Le 1j du matin frappe encore. J'ai lu les exemples trop vite: ceux qui se trouvaient à montrer un genre avaient un sujet féminin ><