# Les pourcentages sont-ils pluriels ou singuliers ?

Tags: grammaire, nombres, accord

Dans la phrase

> 80% des gens sont heureux.

Ne devrait-on pas plutôt utiliser le singulier ?

Je pose la question car il me semble avoir entendu des gens dire

> **Le** 80% des gens…

Réciproquement, quand le sujet est « la majorité des gens » le verbe est singulier. Pourtant les gens utilisent souvent le pluriel.

EDITION: L'expression « **Le** 80% des gens » semble fausse d'après les réponses. Cependant je me demande si ce n'est pas un régionalisme romand car il ne sonne pas faux à mon oreille.

Comment: Question connexe : [Dans quels cas les sujets au singulier décrivant une multitude se conjuguent-ils comme des pluriels ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/dans-quels-cas-les-sujets-au-singulier-decrivant-une-multitude-se-conjuguent-ils)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La règle en français est que l'accord se fait en suivant la logique et donc avec des sujets comme *la majorité des gens* on peut faire l'accord du verbe au singulier (pour insister sur le fait majoritaire) ou au pluriel (pour insister sur les individus).

Avec *80% des gens*, le problème ne se pose pas, on a le choix entre le pluriel dû à 80 et le pluriel des gens.

*Le 80% des gens* est pour moi incorrect. *Les 80% des gens* me semble correct mais j'ai du mal à imaginer un contexte où l'employer sans ajouter quelque chose, par exemple *les 80 premiers pourcents des gens*.  Dans ce cas, l'article défini met tellement le pourcentage en évidence qu'accorder sur les gens me choque.  Naturellement, pour que ça fasse une différence il faut un singulier, donc après *le dernier pourcent des gens* je mets un verbe au singulier.

Comment: Pour moi, _Les 80% des gens_ n'est pas correct.

Comment: @Zistoloen, que penses-tu de « Et les 80% des gens qui ne sont pas d'accord avec toi, tu en fais quoi ? »  Le problème avec le fragment _les 80% des gens_ est qu'il faut un contexte qui accepte l'article défini, mais c'est un problème de sens, pas de grammaire.  Dans les cas où il ne faut pas préciser de quel 80% il s'agit, laisser tomber aussi le _des gens_ est le plus naturel.

Comment: Je dirais plutôt "Et les 80% DE gens qui ne sont pas d'accord avec toi". Sinon, je suis d'accord pour dire que c'est plus un problème de sens que de grammaire.

Comment: @Zistoloen, on retombe dans la différence entre défini et indéfini. Pour que le _des_ sonne juste, il faut se placer mentalement dans un contexte ou _les gens_ ne désigne pas la totalité de la population mais un sous-ensemble.

Comment: Jusqu'à vous lire, pour moi 80% représentait 0.8 de la population totale (*des gens*) ce qui est inférieur à 1 donc singulier. Je vois ici que cette opinion n'est pas partagée, je vais donc reconsidérer mon point de vue.

Answer (score 9):

Je confirme le régionalisme.

En Suisse Romande on assimile 80%, à la moitié, au tiers ou à la majorité (en syntaxe, pas en quantité). C'est alors un singulier.

Ce n'est pas le cas en Lyonnais, en Jurassien et, il ne me semble pas non plus, en Savoyard. Donc, à Genève qui n'a jamais pu se décider entre Romand, Savoyard et Jurassien, on entend:

> - [Le] huitante pourcent des gens a voté.
> - [Les] quatre-vingt pourcent des gens ont voté.

mais jamais:

> - Les huitantes pourcents des gens ont voté.
> - Le quatre-vingt pourcent des gens a voté.

Enfin, d'après mon intuition...

Comment: Éclairage intéressant pour un bordelais bien loin de la Suisse, merci.

Comment: Service ! [Vous diriez "Il n'y pas quoi"]

Comment: Quatre-vingts pour cent, quatre-vingts n'étant pas suivi directement d'une autre quantité.

Answer (score 3):

En fait, ici la règle est la suivante : le singulier ou le pluriel du verbe *être* est choisi en fonction du nombre du sujet dans la phrase.

> 80% des gens sont heureux.

Dans cette phrase, le sujet est *des gens*, on a du pluriel donc on utilise le pluriel du verbe *être* : *sont*.

Même chose, quand le sujet est *la majorité des gens*, on a du singulier donc on utilise le singulier du verbe *être* (*est*) :

> La majorité des gens est heureuse.

Dans cette dernière phrase, certaines personnes pourraient penser que le sujet est *des gens* et donc employer le pluriel du verbe *être* mais pour moi, ce n'est pas le cas, car le sujet est bien *la majorité des gens*.

Sinon, la phrase ci-dessous n'est pas correcte, ça ne se dit pas :

> *Le 80 % des gens

Par contre, on peut dire :

> Les 80 % de gens

Une nouvelle fois, ici, *les* s'accorde avec le sujet *gens* qui est au pluriel.

Comment: Si 80% ne fait pas partie du sujet, comment s'analyse-t'il?

Comment: Ok, j'ai réédité la réponse.

Answer (score -2):

Si vous dites :

> 80% de la Lune est/sont constitué(s) de matériaux...

À mon avis on insiste sur le pourcentage et donc >1% = pluriel, donc *sont constitués...*

Comment: Un pourcentage du tout comme dans l’exemple donné (80% de la Lune) est une fraction plus petite que 1, donc singulier, donc *est constitué de...*