# Quel effet a le fait de partitionner une chose sur son genre et son nombre ?

Tags: grammaire, accord

On dit : « La surface est *couverte* » et « Le pays est *couvert* ». Jusque là, tout va bien.

Mais dit-on:

- « 75% de la surface est couverte » ou bien « 75% de la surface sont *couverts* » ?
- « La majorité du pays est *couvert* » ou bien « La majorité du pays est *couverte* » ?

En d'autres termes, lorsque on partitionne une chose, y a-t-il une règle disant que le groupe nominal garde le genre et le nombre de la chose ou bien doit-il prendre le genre et le nombre de la façon dont la chose est partitionnée?

Comment: Related: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/les-pourcentages-sont-ils-pluriels-ou-singuliers, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/dans-quels-cas-les-sujets-au-singulier-decrivant-une-multitude-se-conjuguent-ils

Answer (score 0):

Ce sont les règles d'accords classiques qui s'appliquent.

> 75% de la surface sont couverts.

Qu'est-ce qui est couvert ? Les *75%* donc masculin pluriel.

> La majorité du pays est couverte.

Qu'est-ce qui est couvert ? La *majorité* donc féminin singulier.

Comment: La règle classique dans ces cas est qu'on fait l'accord suivant ce qu'on veut mettre en évidence.