# Ces phrases sont elles correctes: "14% de la terre pollués sont vendus", "14% de la terre polluée est vendue", "14% de la terre polluée sont vendus"?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, accord, verbes-pronominaux, académie-française

Récemment j'ai appris que après un pourcentage suivi d'un nom, le verbe s'accorde avec soit avec le pourcentage, soit son complément.

Donc, selon cette règle, je pourrais accorder cette phrases comme suivant:

"14% de la terre pollués sont vendus" --> Le complément de ***14%*** est ***la terre***, c'est le 14% qui sont pollués et vendus.

"14% de la terre polluée est vendue" --> Le complément de ***14%*** est ***la terre polluée*** et le participe s'accorde avec le complément.

"14% de la terre polluée sont vendus" --> Le complément de ***14%*** est ***la terre polluée*** et le participe s'accorde avec le pourcentage.

En revanche, si j'aurais écrit: "14% de la terre pollués est vendue", je pense que ce sera incorrect. Êtes vous d'accord?

Mais je reste encore incertaine vue qu'il n'y a pas assez d'exemples sur internet. Quelqu'un pourra me fournir des explications?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/les-pourcentages-sont-ils-pluriels-ou-singuliers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La règle du choix de l'accord et le sens (est-ce toute la terre qui est polluée ou les 14% ?) sont deux choses distinctes qui ont un impact différent sur la phrase. Il y a donc 2x2 = 4 combinaisons possibles.

Par ailleurs pour le deuxième sens, entourer l'adjectif pollué par des virgules pour délimiter le groupe auquel cet adjectif s'applique permet de lever l'ambiguïté.

- Si c'est toute la terre en considération qui est polluée (sens 1) :

> 14% de la terre polluée est vendue
>
> *(accord complément)*

ou

> 14% de la terre polluée sont vendus
>
> *(accord pourcentage)*

.

- Si seuls les 14% vendus sont pollués (sens 2) :

> 14% de la terre, polluée, est vendue
>
> *(accord complément)*

ou

> 14% de la terre, pollués, sont vendus
>
> *(accord pourcentage)*

avec une préférence pour ce dernier qui est complètement non ambigü.

NB: certaines sources signalent aussi un accord possible des pourcentages même > 1% au singulier: https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/accord-du-verbe-avec-une-fraction-un-pourcentage-ou-un-nombre-decimal

Answer (score 1):

14% de la terre polluée est vendue…

14% des terres polluées sont vendues…