# Peut-on accorder de deux manières: "12% d'eau polluée/pollués", "un groupe de personnes connues/connu", "une classe d'élèves agréables/agréable", etc?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, accord, subordonnées, noms-collectifs

Je pense que ces phrases peuvent s'accorder de deux manières selon le sens mais je ne suis pas sûr, voici pourquoi je le pense:

**12% d'eau polluée** -> 12% de quelque chose, cette chose est l'eau polluée.

**12% d'eau pollués** -> 12% de quelque chose, cette chose est l'eau, mais c'est 12% pollués.

**un groupe de personnes connues** -> un groupe de quelque chose, cette chose est des personnes connues.

**un groupe de personnes connu** -> un groupe de quelque chose, cette chose est des personnes, mais c'est un groupe connu.

**une classe d'élèves agréables** -> une classe de quelque chose, cette chose est des élèves agréables.

**une classe d'élèves agréable** -> une classe de quelque chose, cette chose est des élèves, mais c'est une classe agréable.

**une espèce de chiens qui sont beaux** -> une espèce de quelque chose, cette chose est des chiens beaux.

**une espèce de chiens qui est belle** -> une espèce de quelque chose, cette chose est des chiens, mais c'est une espèce belle.

Ps: Le Francais n'est pas la langue maternelle, je m'excuse si la question vous demeure idiote ou anodine.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/dans-quels-cas-les-sujets-au-singulier-d%c3%a9crivant-une-multitude-se-conjuguent-ils https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/les-pourcentages-sont-ils-pluriels-ou-singuliers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1/** 12% d'eau polluée -> 12% de quelque chose, **ces 12 % sont de** l'eau polluée. *Correct*

**2/** 12% d'eau pollués -> 12% de quelque chose, cette chose est **de** l'eau, mais **il y en a** 12%  pollués. *Correct*

**3/** un groupe de personnes connues -> un groupe de quelque chose, cette chose est des personnes connues. *Correct*

**4/** un groupe de personnes connu -> un groupe de quelque chose, cette chose est des personnes, mais c'est un groupe **connu**. *Correct*

**5/** une classe d'élèves agréables -> une classe de quelque chose, cette chose est des élèves agréables. *Correct*

**6/** une classe d'élèves agréable -> une classe de quelque chose, cette chose est des élèves, mais c'est une classe agréable. *Correct, mais on dira plutôt « une classe agréable » voir  [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une+classe+difficile%2Cune+classe+d%27%C3%A9l%C3%A8ves+difficile&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20classe%20difficile%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cune%20classe%20difficile%3B%2Cc0).*

[image]

**7/** une espèce de chiens qui sont beaux -> une espèce de quelque chose, cette chose est **constituée de beaux chiens**. *Correct*

**8/** une espèce de chiens qui est belle -> une espèce de quelque chose, cette chose est **constituée de** chiens, mais c'est **une belle espèce**. *Correct*