# “Seule une poignée de” or “seuls une poignée de”: which to use?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, noms-collectifs

> Même à Lubarn, ***seule/seuls*** une poignée d’individus connaît la vérité à son sujet. »

(Even in Lubarn, only a handful of individuals know the truth about it.)

I have two related questions:

- Should the word "seul" agree with the feminine singular "poignée" or the masculine plural "individus"?
- Is the use of "connaissent" wrong?

So... which of these four versions is considered correct?

1. *seule une poignée d’individus connaît*
2. *seuls une poignée d’individus connaît*
3. *seule une poignée d’individus connaissent*
4. *seuls une poignée d’individus connaissent*

Comment: The subject is *une poignée*, so yes, *connaissent* would be quite wrong since it's the third person plural conjugation, and *une poignée* is singular.

Comment: So this is in stark contrast to how it works in English, as we never say "only a handful of individuals know**s**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Seule une poignée d'individus ....

*Seul* a ici le sens de *seulement*, et non pas de séparation.

C'est donc *une poignée de ...* qui *connaît*.
Les  individus sont inclus dans la poignée, et lui 'transmettent' la capacité de connaître.

Sinon on aurait écrit :

- Très peu d'individus connaissent...
- Les individus qui connaissent ... sont une poignée.

Et là ce sont les individus qui connaissent, même s'ils sont peu nombreux.

---

***EDIT*** Suite aux différents commentaires

Au § *[Le verbe a pour sujet un nom collectif](http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_1_11_accord_du_verbe_avec_un_seul_sujet.shtml)*, le verbe lié à *poignée*  peut être au singulier ou au pluriel.

- Pris dans son *sens figuré*, (ce sont les individus qui connaissent) le verbe est au pluriel.
- Pris dans son *sens de nombre*, (c'est la poignée qui limite de qui est connu) le verbe est au singulier.

La construction spécifique de la phrase induit, sans obligation pour autant,  le verbe au singulier :

Du fait de la présence de *seule* avant ce 'nombre' (qui est un nom et non une adjectif indéfini, un adverbe indéfini ou un pronom), ce n'est plus un nombre quelconque, mais ce nombre particulier (une poignée) qui détermine où est la connaissance des individus.
Seule cette *poignée* référence chaque individu qui connaît la vérité.

Il faut noter que dans un discours ou au théâtre, l'intonation principale sera mise sur *Seule une poignée*, et non sur *individus*.
Avec la prosodie, c'est *connaît* qui apporte l'écho du rythme.

Il serait intéressant de connaître le choix de l'auteur, qui aurait pu écrire avec un verbe au pluriel en utilisant *seul* : *Seuls quelques individus connaissent*.

---

<sup>*N.B. : Cette construction grammaticale est savamment appelée [2.2 Syllepse selon le nombre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllepse)*.</sup>

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord. Dans le cas précis, ce sont bien les individus qui agissent, qui connaissent, je pense donc que le pluriel conviendrait mieux, non ?

Comment: @LaurentS. -- J'ai complété ma réponse pour prendre en compte la particularité de *seul*.

Comment: Je parlait en fait du verbe... selon moi la formulation "Seule une poignée d'individus connaissent..." est la plus correcte, mais vous êtes manifestement bien plus fin connaisseur de la langue que moi qui ai tendance à travailler à l'instinct, donc sans-doute ne suis-je pas dans le bon...

Comment: @LaurentS. Puisqu'il y a un article, c'est poignée qui est le sujet Cf http://french.stackexchange.com/a/2771/848

Comment: @cl-r: note qu'ici "une" est un article indéfini

Comment: Oui, mais c'est un *nom* qui suit, ce n'est ni un *pronom*, ni un *adjectif*, ni un *adverbe* qui donnerait les deux orthographes possibles.

Answer (score 1):

Like with all mass nouns (*poignée, plupart, majorité, moitié, partie, quantité*...), it can be interpreted as referring to *one* handful, hence singular, or as referring to several people, hence plural. **Both options are correct** ; there is no rule forbidding one or the other, beyond personal preference and style.

[This question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/dans-quels-cas-les-sujets-au-singulier-d%C3%A9crivant-une-multitude-se-conjuguent-ils) has a more detailed answer on the subject of mass nouns.

Comment: I've just jotted down four possible versions. Are they all correct, by any chance?

Comment: Maybe in Canadian French, but in French French it seems more common to agree with the mass noun.

Comment: @régénérée no, you need to pick one or the other : "seuls une poignée d'individus connaissent" or "seule une poignée d'individu connaît". If you choose to agree with the mass noun, stick to it. 
@ Law29 my experience as a French French disagrees. I encounter one roughly as often as the other.

Answer (score 1):

There are two grammatically correct possibilities that do not mean the same thing:

- (1) Seule une poignée d'individus connaît.
- (2) Seuls, une poignée d'individus connaissent.

In (1) you consider that the unit composed of the ones who know is alone, so the ones who know probably know each other. Among themselves they probably know each other knows.

In (2) you consider that each guy who knows is alone, and may not know the others know.

As you want to use "seul" as "only" and not "alone", you must go for (1).

Comment: La tournure de la phrase (2) est litigieuse : avec *seul**s,*** ce n'est pas un nom précédé d'un article qu'il faudrait mais un adjectif indéfini ou un adverbe indéfini comme *quelque* (http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/quelque) Cf. les exemples de http://french.stackexchange.com/a/2771/848

Comment: Mon commentaire était faux, mais il me semble que tu as tort aussi. Dans l'exemple sur "la file de clients s'allonge", on explique que si on accorde avec "file" et pas avec "clients" c'est parce que les gens ne s'allongent pas, et pas parce que "la" est un article. La règle est que quand il n'y a pas d'article on accorde toujours avec "les clients", alors que quand il y en a un on a le choix (sauf dans quelques cas spécifiques).

Comment: J'ai ajouté un "edit" à ma réponse. *Seul**s,*** ne semble pas correct, sinon il faudrait une seconde virgule pour le déconnecter de poignée, ce qui rendrait la phrase bancale.

Comment: Tu veux dire "Seuls, , une poignée...", avec deux virgules? Ca me parait vraiment absurde

Comment: Pour  rattacher *seul**s*** à *individus*, il faut isoler *poignée* : *Seuls, une poignée, d'individus connaissent...* ou la remplacer par *quelques*.