# Comment accorde-t-on "L'essentiel de <objet>"

Tags: adjectifs, accord

Dans une construction avec *"l'essentiel de"*, accorde-t-on avec l'objet ou avec essentiel ?

Par exemple pour un **accord en genre**, dit-on:

> *"l'essentiel de la journée était ensoleillée"*
>   
> ou
>   *"l'essentiel de la journée était ensoleillé"* ?

Pour un **accord en nombre**, dit-on:

> *"l'essentiel des troupes sont arrivées"*
>   
> ou
>   *"l'essentiel des troupes est arrivé"* ?

Dans un exemple plus subtil où **genre et nombre sont déduits** de l'accord, dit-on:

> *"l'essentiel des athlètes est inscrit à la même fédération"*
>   
> ou
>   *"l'essentiel des athlètes sont inscrites à la même fédération"* ?

Y a-t-il une règle plus générale qui dicte comment se fait l'accord dans une construction de ce type ? Notamment, ce cas est-il assimilable à l'accord pour les **noms collectifs**, que certains ont cité ?

Comment: Pour moi la situation est semblable à http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2770/176; l'accord se fait suivant le sens désiré.

Comment: Ah merci, c'est effectivement une construction très proche.

Comment: Ce serait intéressant de généraliser la question un peu : je suis d'accord que le verbe s'accorde avec "l'essentiel", mais il y a d'autres formations assez proches pour lesquelles on peut se poser la question... Par exemple je pense qu'on dirait plutôt "la plupart des avocats sont mûrs" et non "la plupart des avocats est mûre". Que dire de "une majorité de...", "une minorité de...", y a-t-il une règle ?

Comment: @jiliagre, Je ne vois pas ce que vient faire _morceau_ qui n'est pas vraiment un collectif en général et certainement pas dans _le morceau d'orange_.   Les collectifs en français s'accordent suivant le sens désiré. (_Essentiel de la journée_, c'est pas un usage collectif, donc l'accord est avec essentiel.  Le sens d'essentiel me laisse penser qu'accorder avec _essentiel_ plutôt qu'avec le complément est souvent ce qui sera désiré même dans les usages comme collectif.)

Answer (score 6):

Les termes *collectifs* sont sujets au même choix.

**Les deux sont possibles, lorsqu'il s'agit d'un collectif au pluriel, avec une préférence pour le pluriel.**

Il s'agit d'un **syllepse** de nombre.

- L'essentiel des problèmes + singulier/pluriel.

ATTENTION: l'essentiel de cette affaire est résolue (pas de pluriel possible).

- La majorité des élèves + singulier/pluriel.
- la plus grande partie des erreurs + singulier/pluriel.
- l'ensemble des participants + singulier/pluriel.
- la totalité des participants + singulier/pluriel.

idem avec *la plupart*, *un troupeau*, *une bande de* ...

> La plupart s'en allaient chercher une autre terre ("Les Membres et
>   l'Estomac", Jean de la Fontaine)

Le Grand Robert:

> Cour. LA PLUPART DE... (suivi d'un pluriel): le plus grand nombre
>   de... - Généralité, majorité. La plupart des hommes, des enfants
>   sont... . La plupart de ceux qui... . La plupart d'eux (vx), d'entre
>   eux, d'entre nous. - Dans la plupart des cas. Chez la plupart des
>   peuples. - REM. L'accord, dans l'usage ancien, se faisait aussi avec
>   la plupart et non avec son complément au pluriel; cet emploi est un
>   archaïsme littér.: «La plupart des vivants n'attend rien...» (-
>   Immolation, Suarès). Cf. Tristan Derème, Alain, André Billy, cités par
>   Grevisse, le Bon Usage, § 806, Rem. 2.

Mais ceux-ci seraient plutôt utilisés avec un singulier (il y a un sens supplémentaire à collection, liste) :

- la collection des livres + singulier.
- la liste des courses + singulier.
- le groupe des participants + singulier.

Comment: J'ai n'ai rien trouvé dans la littérature où j'ai toujours vu l'accord au singulier. J'ai en revanche trouvé cette phrase sur [un site officiel](http://www.gouvernement.fr/raymond-barre) « **L’essentiel** des personnalités politiques françaises **sont** présentes lors des obsèques de Raymond Barre au Val-de-Grâce… » mais je dois avouer qu'il ne m'a pas convaincu. J'aimerais une référence plus solide…

Comment: @jlliagre - dans Grévisse, mais je ne l'ai pas sous la main. Dewaele aussi: https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/la-plupart-est-ou-la-plupart-sont/

Comment: Oui, bien sûr. Je suis tout à fait d'accord pour « la plupart » et les autres noms collectifs habituels. La question que je me pose est de savoir si « l'essentiel » en fait partie. Je me trompe peut-être mais j'ai plutôt tendance à considérer « l'essentiel » non pas comme une collection mais comme une qualité que l'on extrait comme avec « le meilleur, la crème, l'élite, etc.  » pour lesquels il me semble que le pluriel est impossible: « Le meilleur des troupes *sont arrivées* » « La crème des troupes *sont arrivées* » « L'élite des troupes *sont arrivées* »

Comment: Il y a au moins une vraie grosse différences d'usage. "La plupart" s'accorde 5x plus souvent au pluriel qu'au singulier d'après Google Ngram viewer, tandis que "L'essentiel" ne semble presque jamais s'accorder au pluriel.
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=l%27essentiel+des+*+sont%2Cl%27essentiel+des+*+est&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+plupart+des+*+sont%2Cla+plupart+des+*+est&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3

Comment: Intéressant : "majorité" s'accordait au début du XIXè siècle au singulier le plus souvent, mais maintenant le plus souvent au pluriel. https://goo.gl/ZK76jA

Comment: @qoba Mon premier commentaire faisait aussi référence à une recherche sur books.google.com où je n'ai trouvé **aucun** accord au pluriel avec « l'essentiel ».

Comment: L'académie française va dans le sens de cette réponse: http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#54_strong-em-nom-collectif-suivi-d-un-complment-au-pluriel-accord-du-verbe-em-strong

Comment: J'ai bien aimé votre tentative de systématisation. C'est fort difficile ce sujet. Merci !

Comment: Au moment où _l'essentiel_ deviendrait l'entièreté, il n'y aurait tout de même qu'une seule affaire dans l'exemple où le pluriel est impossible. On dirait «toute l'affaire», contrairement à tous les autres exemples, qui deviendraient «tous» ou «toutes». (+1)

Answer (score 5):

C'est la seconde forme qui est employée :

> L'essentiel de la journée était ensoleillé. L'essentiel des troupes est arrivé.

Ici *l'essentiel de la journée* est un groupe sujet, mais on parle toujours de *l'essentiel*. On s'en rend peut-être plus facilement compte sur une phrase comme :

> Le chant des oiseaux m'apaise (et non pas <strike>m'apaisent</strike>),
>
> Une minorité d'oiseaux chante (<strike>chantent</strike>) faux.

Comment: "Le chant des oiseaux" n'est pas un bon exemple, car le chant n'est pas un ensemble d'oiseaux. Ce qui rend la question intéressante c'est que "l'essentiel des troupes" est toujours des "troupes"

Comment: @qoba J'ai rajouté un second exemple, dont la forme est plus semblable à celle de la question. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Les usages varient et je n'ai pas d'information précise sur *l'essentiel de*, et donc c'est simplement de l'eau au moulin. Mais si on peut établir un parallèle entre un type d'emploi et le sens attribué à *l'essentiel de* selon le contexte, cela constitue un exercice intéressant, mais qui ne saurait être déterminant. On a peu de mérite à présenter, de manière non-exhaustive, ce qu'on trouve au *LBU* en ce qui a trait à la construction *nom et pseudo-complément*, reste que ça illustre la grande richesse des usages et le contexte dans lequel s'articule à mon avis la question (on parsème de quelques liens à la BDL pour fins de comparaison, que je n'effectue pas) :

> - Avec [*espèce, façon, genre, manière, sorte, type*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2743) avec la préposition    *de* suivie d'un nom, c'est lui qui donne l'accord...
>     dans certains cas...
>
>   - Si le complément représente l'idée générale, le nom précédant a    essentiellement la fonction d'un adjectif. Mais si espèce etc. est
>       employé dans son sens ordinaire, en particulier avec un déterminant
>       démonstratif, alors il donne l'accord.
>   - *Espèce de* peut se comporter tellement comme un adjectif que son    déterminant peut prendre le genre du nom qui suit, à l'oral comme à
>       l'écrit !
>   - Si c'est précédé de *toute*, c'est le nom suivant qui donne l'accord.
>   - Avec *force* sans préposition (litt., mais illustrant la fonction de    déterminant), *[nombre de](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4143), [la plupart de](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=1650), quantité de*,
>       c'est le nom    qui suit qui donne l'accord.
> - Avec les expressions nominales exprimant la quantité globale et la    fraction, et avec *pour cent*, *pour mille*, l'accord se fait avec le 
>     nom qui suit selon qu'il est un pseudo-complément. Ces expressions
>     sont associées à la fonction de déterminant.
>
>   - Les noms du type *douzaine*, *centaine*, *millier* sont fortement sentis    comme déterminants.
>   - Un nom exprimant la grande quantité (ex. [*infinité de*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=infinit%C3%A9&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=5163)) cède souvent    sa fonction de donneur d'accord au nom qui le suit. Mais
>       c'est selon    l'importance que souhaite donner l'auteur au nom ou
>       influence de la    règle générale et il y a foule de nuances, comme
>       justement avec    *foule de*.
>   - Les deux accords sont possibles ici (quantité) avec *nombre de* et    *quantité de* à l'exclusion des cas précités, mais on semble préférer l'accord avec nom qui suit.
>   - Avec les fractions proprement dites, soit d'expressions avec *part,    partie, fraction*, ou *[la majorité, la minorité](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=1682), le reste*, on dit    qu'il y a concurrence et que l'accord avec le nom
>       complété est    surtout fréquent quand c'est purement orthographique.
>       Mais aussi    fréquent lorsque le nom des fractions est au pluriel et
>       le complément    au singulier, ou lorsque le nom ou *la majorité*, *la
>       minorité* sont pris    strictement dans leur sens mathématique, ou
>       avec *le reste*. *Le commun de* serait une    locution figée avec son
>       propre usage.
>   - *Pour cent, pour mille* fonctionnent un peu comme les fractions et on    trouve les deux types d'accord.
> - Avec des emplois collectifs qui ne sont pas perçus comme déterminants de quantité (*[troupe](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=1443), troupeau, unité*, dans
>     certains contextes, par exemple), c'est eux qui *ordinairement*
>     donnent l'accord, tout comme quand ils sont précédés d'un article
>     défini ou du déterminant démonstratif ou possessif (« La foule des
>     vivants rit et suit sa folie », Victor Hugo, [Dans le cimetière de ***](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Dans_le_cimeti%C3%A8re_de_***) ds. *Les Rayons et les Ombres*). Mais l'accord est
>     possible avec le nom complément quand il est perçu comme le cœur du
>     syntagme, c'est-à-dire comme un pseudo-complément, mais on le dit
>     moins naturel quand le nom complété est précédé de l'article défini.
>
> [ En plus de la structure de l'article, on paraphrase copieusement le
>   *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, § 431, incluant la note R12 pour l'exemple qui suit. ]

---

Grevisse et Goosse ont déniché un merveilleux exemple pour les collectifs, pragmatique à souhait, où l'auteur aborde d'abord collectivement (le triangle) puis individuellement (les canards, plusieurs individus) son sujet :

> Un long triangle de canards vole très bas, comme s'ils voulaient
>   prendre terre ; mais tout à coup la cabane, où le *caleil* est allumé, les 
>   éloigne : celui qui tient la tête de la colonne dresse le cou, remonte,
>   et tous les autres derrière lui s'emportent plus haut avec des cris
>   sauvages.
>
> [ Alphonse Daudet, [*Lettres de mon moulin*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/36780/36780-h/36780-h.htm#page_279), 267 ]

---

Selon moi *l'essentiel* n'est pas un collectif dans le sens expliqué. Je l'associe davantage à la quantité, alors que l'essentiel de la *journée*, que c'en soit la majorité ou plus grande partie du 24 heures ou la majorité du temps où l'ensoleillement est possible, c'est a priori un sens mathématique selon moi (et donc journée pourrait donner l'accord) ; mais pas *strictement* (comparer avec l'exemple du LBU : *la majorité des députés rejeta le projet*). Ce serait la même chose pour les *troupes* et les *athlètes*, mais on pourrait peut-être vouloir dire la partie la plus importante d'un point de vue qualitatif, et dans ce cas on pourrait choisir l'accord avec *l'essentiel* (masc. sing.). On peut certainement dire que la *quantité* est un vecteur servant à la catégorisation de certains usages, mais le choix demeure et on hésite...