# Accords dans une phrase avec "nombre" et "équipement"

Tags: accord, pluriel, constructions

> Un nombre restreint d'équipements n'étaient pas à jour.

Quels sont les accords corrects dans cette phrase?

- *équipement* ou *équipement**s***? On parle d'un nombre, donc je penche pour le pluriel mais visuellement quelque chose ne me va pas dans le contexte d'*équipement* qui porte déjà au singulier l'idée du pluriel (*l'équipement d'un astronaute* implique par exemple plusieurs éléments).
- *était* ou *étai**ent***? On parle du nombre (donc singulier) d'une part, et de plusieurs machines qui ne l'étaient pas d'autre part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il y a plusieurs équipements et ce sont ces derniers qui n'étaient pas à jour, pas leur nombre (restreint), donc la phrase est correcte : pluriel pour les deux.

> Un nombre restreint d'équipements n'étaient pas à jour.

Le singulier est aussi possible si l'on considère « le nombre restreint d'équipements » comme un tout:

> Un nombre restreint d'équipements n'était pas à jour.

Comment: Merci. Est-ce que ce n'est pas en contradiction avec [une autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2774/695) qui suggère qu'"était" pourrait aussi être "étaient"?

Comment: Oui, c'est vrai. Ma réponse est en contradiction avec elle. Le singulier est possible pour le verbe si l'on considère « le nombre restreint d'équipements » comme un tout, ce que je n'ai pas fait mais qui se défend.

Comment: C'est le même principe que "la majorité des Français est/sont..." et tous les autres trucs du genre, ça doit avoir un nom d'ailleurs.