# Personne..ne + pronom d'objet direct: les règles de l'accord

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord

J'essaye de construire la phrase suivante:

> On peut plus en parler plus tard, étant donné que ***personne*** d'autre ne m'a pas encore demandé de venir **l'aider**. (en: We can discuss it more later, since ***nobody*** has asked me to help **them** yet.)

Ce qui me rend pas très sûr de la grammaticalité de la phrase est le pronom d'objet direct. En anglais, on utilise **them**, qui est en fait au pluriel, même si ce n'est pas grammaticale (ça devient de plus en plus un remplaçant pour *him or her*, grammaticalement la forme 'neutre' du singulier, parce que *him or her* est très lourd même à l'écrit).

Et donc en français j'ai envie de mettre au singulier *l'*, parce que *personne..ne* est au singulier ; c'est logique. Mais mon esprit anglophone veut que cela soit *les aider*, parce qu'en réalité je fais référence au **groupe de personnes (pluriel)** qui *ne m'ont pas encore demandé*.

Qu'est-ce qui est correcte dans ce cas ? Je ne peux plus rationellement réfléchir... je suis perdu entre les deux langues.

---

I am trying to construct the following sentence:

> On peut plus en parler plus tard, étant donné que ***personne*** d'autre ne m'a pas encore demandé de venir **l'aider**. (en: We can discuss it more later, since ***nobody*** has asked me to help **them** yet.)

What makes me not very sure about the grammaticality of the sentence is the direct object pronoun. In English, we use **them**, which is in fact plural, even if it is not grammatical (it is becoming more and more a substitute for *him or her*, grammatically the 'neutral' form of the singular because *him or her* is very dense even in writing).

And so in French I want to put in the singular *l'*, because *personne..ne* is singular; it's logical. But my anglophone mind wants it to be *les aider*, because in fact I am referring to the **group of people (plural)** who *have not asked me yet*.

What is correct in this case? I can't think about it rationally anymore... I am lost between the two languages.

Answer (score 2):

> On peut en parler plus tard,

or, a stretch,

> On peut en parler plus, plus tard,

would work. Your version, “plus en parler plus tard” seems wrong to me (native French).

> étant donné que personne d'autre ne m'a encore demandé de venir l'aider.

I dropped the “pas”.

Also “personne” is singular in French. In English the absence of potential things is plural (there is no cars), but in French if there's none, there definitely isn't many. To me, it's more natural. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If we start from your English sentence:

> We can discuss it more later, since nobody has asked me to help them yet.

In the second part, we have *nobody* coupled with *them*, in French *personne* and some unknown pronoun...

Let’s see some simpler sentences:

- Personne ne **l**’a su → *Nobody learnt about* ***it***
- Personne ne **l**’a vu → *Nobody saw* ***him/her/it*** <sub>(eventually **them** when uncertain of the gender)</sub>
- Personne ne **les** as vu → *Nobody saw* ***them***

If we now wonder how many people would get help, if help was requested, it would likely be one at a time for individual work, or likely a team at a time (i.e. many people) for team work. French would lean towards singular in the first case, and plural in the second:

- ...personne ne m’a encore demandé de l’aider → *people come seek help one by one*
- ...personne ne m’a encore demandé de les aider → *groups of people come to seek help together*

The latter could be reworded with *aucune équipe* instead of *personne*, but then more questions and more answers arise with the collective noun *(discussed in more details [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/dans-quels-cas-les-sujets-au-singulier-d%c3%a9crivant-une-multitude-se-conjuguent-ils/2771#2771)):*

- ...**aucune équipe** ne m’a encore demandé de l’aider/les aider

---

However, and just as a side-note, I would not word the sentence like this, though it might be a strictly personal point of view. In speech, and among many many variations, I would probably choose something close to:

- On pourra en **re**parler plus tard, puisque personne [n’]est encore venu demander de l’aide.